# Symfony Finder: Finding all directories except ones that start with an underscore

Tags: php, regex, symfony, finder

I want to find all directories (at root level, not recursive) that do not start with an underscore.

getcwd() = /Users/example/project

Directory example:

```
/Users/example/project/_pictures
/Users/example/project/_graphics
/Users/example/project/test
```

I've tried with the following code snippet:

```
$directories = $this->container->get('finder')
    ->directories()
    ->in(getcwd())
    ->notName('_*')
    ->depth(0);
```

But this seems to return:

```
/Users/example/project/_pictures/home
/Users/example/project/test
```

So it returns "test", which is correct, but it also returns a sub-folder inside one that starts with an underscore, which is incorrect. Any ideas what's gone wrong here?

Comment: You code seems to be working as  desired , make sure you are using latest version and setting depth `->depth(0);`

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
$directories = glob(getcwd() . '/[!^_]*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
```

But hoped for a solution using the Symfony finder.

Answer (score 1):

I found in `Finder::searchInDirectory`:

```
if (static::IGNORE_DOT_FILES === (static::IGNORE_DOT_FILES & $this->ignore)) {
    $this->notPaths[] = '#(^|/)\..+(/|$)#';
}
```

Modify with this and it work :)

```
$finder->notPath('#(^|/)_.+(/|$)#')
```

**Update**

This's my code:

```
$finder = Finder::create()
    ->files()
    ->name('*.twig')
    ->notPath('#(^|/)_.+(/|$)#') // Ignore path start with underscore (_).
    ->ignoreVCS(true)
    ->ignoreDotFiles(true)
    ->ignoreUnreadableDirs()
    ->in(__DIR__);

foreach ($finder as $file) {
    var_dump($file->getRelativePath());
}
```

Comment: Could you integrate your `$finder->notPath('#(^|/)_.+(/|$)#')` code into the OPs code as an example of how to implement it? Making sure that you indicate exactly how the string of characters affect the output. Be sure to note if the characters exclude more than the OP has asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Try with $finder->exclude($dirs);

Comment: I tried finding all underscore directories, then adding them to the exclude method but it hasn't worked either.

I was sure there must be a regular expression for this that can be added to notName() that would be faster as well.

Comment: what about notPath($pattern) ?

Comment: If I do path then it will try the pattern on the whole path rather than the actual directory name itself, which will get unnecessarily complicated.